# How to create clean url using .htaccess for 2 parameters or 1

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a webpage with url `website.com/app/` there is an `index.php` in the dir and also an `.htaccess` file.
I want a make this url into a clean url

```
website.com/app/?app=app1&id=12345
```

to

```
website.com/app/app1/12345
```

I was able to achieve this with this rule

```
RewriteEngine On
# Don't match real existing files so CSS, scripts, images aren't rewritten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?app=$1&id=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)index.php?app=$1 [L]
```

but I also want to be able to access the webpage with this url

```
website.com/app/app1
```

so that It'll mean `website.com/app/?app=app1` But currently I get "Object not found!" when trying this. 
Thank you!

Comment: You can either precede above rule with a more specific rule only accepting a single get parameter, or you apply the `?` operator on the second capture group in your regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `RewriteRule`, it will leave you with the URL: `website.com/app/app1`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]*)$ /app/?app=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own qn here :

```
RewriteEngine On
# Don't match real existing files so CSS, scripts, images aren't rewritten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /apps/?app=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?app=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

You're welcome